# Migrate Excel Docs from Shared Drive to Sharepoint Foundation 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, migration, excel, database

I have a fairly large shared drive with various files that need to be migrated over to SharePoint.

I only have full control of my site, which is a subsite within the hierarchy.

I feel like if I were a scripting whiz this would be no problem.

I'm just starting out with about 400 Excel documents that need to go from the shared drive to SharePoint. Just a simple view is needed within SharePoint for relatively easy navigation.

Most workstations have Office 2010 (some 2003).

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't able to write the script yourself, it may be time to hire a consultant. Otherwise you're looking at a manual process.

The method that would take the least amount of clicks in a manual move would be:

> 1) Open the file share in Explorer in one window.
>
> 2) Browse to the destination document library in SharePoint in your browser.
>
> 2007: Under Actions, click "Open with Windows Explorer"
>
> 2010: In the ribbon click "Open with Explorer"
>
> (see images below)

2007:

[image: Open with Windows Explorer]

2010:

[image: Open with Explorer]

> 3) Copy and paste the files from the Explorer window of your file share to the Explorer window of your document library.
>
> 4) Wait.
>
> 5) Wait some more.
>
> (This will take a very long time for a lot of files. You may want to do this on a machine dedicated to this task for the duration of your file move.)

Obviously if the files are all going to different document libraries this will take more user involvement. If you are moving files based on rules, metadata, or folder location, a script is probably the answer for you.

Comment: i'm just a technical aide so they don't expect much from me. pretty sure they tried outsourcing this stuff, but it was costing too much money so they scrapped it. It's a nice part-time gig while i'm in school - but i really want to do this the best possible way. i don't think i can script it becasue of my lack of priveledges. like powershell scripting right? can you point me towards a good book? also, what do you think of nintex forms? they seem pretty legit

Comment: Well then this is your easiest answer. It will just take a long time. A very long time.

Comment: Your best guide for PowerShell scripting is MSDN. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa973757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518673.aspx. If it is 2007 then you can't use PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: Our company is a Nintex reseller so I think my opinion would be biased.

Comment: like the rest of my life long.. tried connecting powershell, no dice. we're workin with 2010 foundation. what about sharepoint designer for complete customization.. is that worth digging into. I've played around wuth it slightly, but I'm no web scripting expert. i get lost in the sea of different platforms, frameworks, etc..

Comment: also.. when i migrate all the folders - everything is checked out me. what's the best way to check in everything at once?

Comment: Your OP says 2007 fyi... SharePoint Designer has a function, but has nothing to do with scripting the move of files from a file system. You can use SharePoint Designer to check in all your files though. Good luck. If you have any more questions please post them as new questions and accept answers to your specific question when they've been addressed. This will encourage other SP-SE members to contribute on your questions.

Comment: No problem. That's what the site's here for.